# Definition of dominance (self-assessment manikin)

Tags: emotion, test, io-psychology, well-being, hci

I'm using the self-assessment manikin to measure valence, arousal and dominance. Valence and arousal is clear to all participants but with the concept of dominance a lot of participants are struggling.

I'm explaining dominance in term of degree of control, i.e. on one side of the scale the participant is feeling completely controlled and influenced and on the other side  completely controlling and dominant.

The participants have to chat with a chat application on a smartphone. Can somebody imagine a chat conversation where the participant is feeling dominant and one where the participant is not feeling dominant at all? I would like to give two such examples to the participants.

Moreover, is the term dominance in relation to an emotion or to an object? For example, during chatting is dominance always in relation to the person the participant is chatting with, i.e. how dominant the participant is feeling in relation to this person?

Comment: We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: A reference to the 'self-assessment manikin' would improve this question. P.s. In case this is [tag:HCI] research, we have a tag for that.